# How to read a text file in java and assign lines to variables

Tags: java, arrays, file-io, java.util.scanner

Here is the code I wrote :

```
    try {   
        String[] Flight_Inputs = null;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(f); // f = input file
        int counter =0;
        while(in.hasNextLine()) {
            Flight_Inputs[counter++] = in.next();
          //Flight_Inputs = in.nextLine().split("\n"); // Also tried this
        }
        in.close(); 
         for(int i = 0,j=0; i < Flight_Inputs.length; i++){
             Boeing.setDestination_from(Flight_Inputs[j++]);
             Boeing.setDestination_to(Flight_Inputs[j++]);
             Boeing.setName(Flight_Inputs[j++]);
         }
```

I am getting Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException error I tried also other variations and got an error that I was trying to access index 1 of Flight_Inputs but compiler says it doesnt exist.

What I want to do do is simply get some lines from the text file and assign them to variables of Boieng object... Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please try and respect Java naming conventions (variable names should begin with a lowercase letter); it makes it easier for people used to Java to give answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never initialized `Flight_Inputs` array, that is why you get `java.lang.NullPointerException`. Anyway in case you don't know how many lines file will contain you should use `List` instead like `ArrayList<String>`.

Try maybe this way:

```
List<String> lines= new ArrayList<String>();
Scanner in = new Scanner(f); // f = input file
while(in.hasNextLine()) {
    lines.add(in.nextLine());
}
in.close();
```

Now to iterate over this list you can use

```
for(String line: lines){
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man you saved me once again, works, I also guessed about unknown size but I was using ArrayList for almost everything, every Object list ... and wanted to avoid simple string ...thought strings can have unlimited size, because you can concatenate them etc. well I was wrong need more practice! Thanks again!

Comment: Although I used `ArrayList<String> lines= new ArrayList<String>();` List gave the error : The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String>, I would like to know why for self improvement! :)

Comment: @Anarkie I suspect that you imported `java.awt.List` instead `java.util.List`.

Answer (score 4):

You should change your Flight_Inputs to a dynamic size list, for example:

change:

```
//as Pshemo pointed out, this is null, 
//and is causing your NullPointerException
String[] Flight_Inputs = null;
...
Flight_Inputs[counter++] = in.nextLine();
...
for(int i = 0,j=0; i < Flight_Inputs.length; i++){
```

to:

```
List<String> Flight_Inputs = new ArrayList<String>();
...
Flight_Inputs.add(in.next());
...
for(String filghtInput : Flight_Inputs){
```

Comment: +1 for nice format of the answer. BTW OP should probably use `nextLine()` instead of `next()`.

Answer (score 2):

Well yes, `String[] Flight_Inputs = null;` means that... `Flight_Inputs` is null.

You would need to instantiate it with a non null value, for example:

```
String[] Flight_Inputs = new String[size];
```

except that you probably don't know the size beforehand.

A simpler alternative if y ou use Java 7:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file, charset);
```